# Java custom Sort by 2 parts of same string

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have seen other questions like this, but couldn't adapt any of the information to my code.  Either because it wasn't specific to my issue or I couldn't get my head around the answer.  So, I am hoping to ask "how" with my specific code.  Tell me if more is needed.

I have various files (all jpg's) with names with the format "20140214-ddEventBlahBlah02.jpg" and "20150302-ddPsBlagBlag2".

I have a custom comparator in use that sorts things in a Windows OS fashion... i.e.  02,2,003,4,4b,4c,10, etc.  Instead of the computer way of sorting, which was screwed up.  Everything is good, except I now want to sort these strings using 2 criteria in the strings.

1)  The date (in the beginning). i.e. 20150302
2)  The rest of the filename after the "-" i.e. ddPsBlagBlag2

I am currently using the comparator for a project that displays these files in reverse order.  They are displaying according to what was added most recently.  i.e. 20150302 is displaying before 20140214.  Which is good.  But I would like the files, after being sorted by date in reverse order, to display by name in normal Windows OS ascending order (not in reverse).

Code:

```
Collections.sort(file, new Comparator<File>() 
                    {
                    private final Comparator<String> NATURAL_SORT = new WindowsExplorerComparator();

                    @Override
                    public int compare(File o1, File o2) 
                    {
                        return NATURAL_SORT.compare(o1.getName(), o2.getName());
                    }
                });
                Collections.reverse(file);
```

The code above takes the ArayList of file names and sends it to the custom WindowsExplorerComparator class.  After being sorted, Collections.reverse() is called on the ArrayList.

Code:

```
    class WindowsExplorerComparator implements Comparator<String> 
    {
    private static final Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d\\.|\\s");

@Override
public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
    Iterator<String> i1 = splitStringPreserveDelimiter(str1).iterator();
    Iterator<String> i2 = splitStringPreserveDelimiter(str2).iterator();
    while (true) 
    {
        //Til here all is equal.
        if (!i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        //first has no more parts -> comes first
        if (!i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        //first has more parts than i2 -> comes after
        if (i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) 
        {
            return 1;
        }

        String data1 = i1.next();
        String data2 = i2.next();
        int result;
        try 
        {
            //If both datas are numbers, then compare numbers
            result = Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data1), Long.valueOf(data2));
            //If numbers are equal than longer comes first
            if (result == 0) 
            {
                result = -Integer.compare(data1.length(), data2.length());
            }
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
        {
            //compare text case insensitive
            result = data1.compareToIgnoreCase(data2);
        }

        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}

private List<String> splitStringPreserveDelimiter(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = splitPattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int pos = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(str.substring(pos, matcher.start()));
        list.add(matcher.group());
        pos = matcher.end();
    }
    list.add(str.substring(pos));
    return list;
}
```

}

The code above is the custom WindowsExplorerComperator class being used to sort the ArrayList.

So, an example of what I would like the ArrayList to look like after being sorted (and date sort reversed) is:

```
20150424-ssEventBlagV002.jpg
20150323-ssEventBlagV2.jpg
20150323-ssEventBlagV3.jpg
20150323-ssEventBlagV10.jpg
20141201-ssEventZoolander.jpg
20141102-ssEventApple1.jpg
```

As you can see, first sorted by date (and reversed), then sorted in ascending order by the rest of the string name.

Is this possible?  Please tell me its an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  In the end, I used the code from pathfinderelite, with some changes.   All my changes are in comments underneath pathfinderelites answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you should do:

First, you need to fix your split expression as @ug_ stated.  However, I think splitting on numbers is more appropriate.

```
private static final Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

which, for `20150323-ssEventBlagV2.jpg` will result in

```
[, 20150323, -ssEventBlagV, 2, .jpg]
```

Second, perform a date comparison separate from your Long comparison.  Using `SimpleDateFormat` will make sure you are only comparing numbers that are formatted as dates.

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    result = sdf.parse(data2).compareTo(sdf.parse(data1));
    if (result != 0) {
        return result;
    }
} catch (final ParseException e) {
    /* continue */
}
```

Last, swap the order of your Long compare

```
Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data2), Long.valueOf(data1));
```

And you should be good to go.  Full code below.

```
private static final Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        Iterator<String> i1 = splitStringPreserveDelimiter(str1).iterator();
        Iterator<String> i2 = splitStringPreserveDelimiter(str2).iterator();
        while (true) {
            // Til here all is equal.
            if (!i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) {
                return 0;
            }
            // first has no more parts -> comes first
            if (!i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
                return -1;
            }
            // first has more parts than i2 -> comes after
            if (i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) {
                return 1;
            }

            String data1 = i1.next();
            String data2 = i2.next();
            int result;

            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                result = sdf.parse(data1).compareTo(sdf.parse(data2));
                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            } catch (final ParseException e) {
                /* continue */
            }

            try {
                // If both datas are numbers, then compare numbers
                result = Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data2),
                        Long.valueOf(data1));
                // If numbers are equal than longer comes first
                if (result == 0) {
                    result = -Integer.compare(data1.length(),
                            data2.length());
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                // compare text case insensitive
                result = data1.compareToIgnoreCase(data2);
            }

            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks good.  Thanks a lot to you and ug.  The only issue that this current code is having is in the sorting at the end of the string name.  Specifically, letters after the numbers and 0's before the numbers.  i.e.       20140526-blEventBlah12 is coming before 20140526-blEventBlah012b which is coming before 20140526-blEventBlah012....      Windows sorting way, should have it...  012 -> 012b -> 12

Comment: Also the name is in reverse order as well.  Only want the date to be in reverse order.  It is currently showing in this order 20140404-agEventBecca -> 20140404-agEventAgent.  Asc order for string name should be other way around.

Comment: Also..  For clarification..  EventBecca.jpg should come before EventBecca0.jpg which should come before EventBecca01.jpg which should come before EventBecca10.jpg

Comment: if (result == 0) 
             {
                 result = -Integer.compare(data2.length(),
                         data1.length());
             }                                                                                                                 I switched around the data1 and data2 here and I managed to get the numbers in order.  Blah -> Blah012 -> Blah12 ...   Still trying to figure out though how to get Blah12 - > Blah12b -> Blah12c.. Its currently going in the opposite direction.  And still trying to get the name part not to be in reverse.. i.e. Blah.jpg -> Aggro.jpg

Comment: I almost got it.  I switched the data1 and data2 around in this code 'catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
             // compare text case insensitive
             result = data2.compareToIgnoreCase(data1);
         }'                                                                                                                Now everything is working....  Almost..  The only thing not working is when it has no number at the end.  i.e.  its going 'Blag -> Blah00b -> Blah00c --> Blah01 -> Blah'  the Blah without numbers should be first, not last...

Comment: Got it working!  Thanks.  Had to change the RegEx statement back to \\d+|\\.|\\s to get it ordering right where EventGolf.jpg comes before EventGold2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your close, whenever dealing with something not working debug your program and make sure that methods are returning what you would expect. When I ran your program first thing I noticed was that EVERY compare iteration which attempted to convert a string to `Long` threw a `NumberFormatException`. This was a big red flag so I threw in some printlns to check what the value of `data1` and `data2` were.

Heres my output:

```
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150424-ssEventBlagV00
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150323-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 3. 2.
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150424-ssEventBlagV00
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150323-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 3. 2.
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV1 20150323-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV1 20150424-ssEventBlagV00
Compare: 20141201-ssEventZoolander.jpg 20150323-ssEventBlagV1
Compare: 20141201-ssEventZoolander.jpg 20150323-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 20141201-ssEventZoolander.jpg 20150323-ssEventBlagV
```

Big thing to notice here is that its trying to convert `3.` and `2.` to long values which of course wont work.

---

The simplest solution with your code is to simply change your regular expression. Although you might go for a more simple route of string iteration instead of regex in the future, I feel as though regex complicates this problem more than it helps.

New regex: `\\d+(?=\\.)|\\s`

Changes:

- `\\d` -> `\\d+` - Capture all digits before the period not just the first one
- `\\.` -> `(?=\\.)` - place period in non capturing group so your method doesn't append it to our digits

New debug output:

```
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150424-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150323-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 3 2
Compare: 20150323-ssEventBlagV 20150323-ssEventBlagV
Compare: 10 3
Compare: 20141201-ssEventZoolander.jpg 20150323-ssEventBlagV
```

As you can see the numbers at the end are actually getting parsed correctly.

---

*One more minor thing:*

Your result for digit comparison is backwards

`result = Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data1), Long.valueOf(data2));`

should be either:

`result = -Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data1), Long.valueOf(data2));`

**or**

`result = Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data2), Long.valueOf(data1));`

because its sorting them backwards.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to edit your WindowsExporerComparator Class so that it performs this sorting.  Given two file names as Strings you need to determine what order they go in using a following high level algorithm.

1. are they the same?  if yes return 0
2. Split the file name into two strings, the date portion and the name portion.
3. Using the date portion convert the string to a date using the Java DateTime and then compare the dates.
4. If the dates are the same compare the two name portions using your current compare code and return the result from that.

This is a bit complicated and sort of confusing, but you will have to do it in one comparator and put in all of your custom logic